# Getting NSDate from Seconds in ObjC

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have got seconds as 54000.
  How can i get the time as 3:00:00 PM ?

Any dateformatter's i can use to get it ?

Thanks

Comment: What should happen on time zone changes?

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate but the answers provided in that question can apply here too. Essentially you have a time interval, with the start point being midnight.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming given seconds are in local time zone and you want to convert to local time zone.

```
NSInteger timeInSeconds = 54000;

NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:timeInSeconds]];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss a"];

NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the time formatted according to the current locale on a "normal" day (i.e. one without time zone changes),

```
double seconds = 54000;

NSDateFormatter * fmt = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:seconds];
NSString * s = [fmt stringFromDate:date];

// If you are not using ARC,
[fmt release];
```